# Python import fails only in certain directory

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, import, scipy

When I try to import opencv from a particular directory (let's call it python_scripts), the python2.7 interpreter will hang. However when I am importing from my home directory (or any other directory than python_scripts), the import works just fine:

```
python2.7
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

I can't see any notable differences between the directories other than the one that works is my home directory and the one that hangs is a directory with a bunch of python scripts in it. There aren't any bash scripts changing the $PYTHONPATH variable.

Another issue is that when I try to import scipy and numpy in my home directory, those work fine. However, in the python_scripts directory, "import scipy" hangs and I get the following errors for numpy:

```
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import scimath as emath
ImportError: cannot import name scimath
```

Other imports such as "import math" or "import random" work fine in the python_scripts directory. It is just the opencv, numpy, and scipy libraries that seem to have a problem.

This hasn't always happened. I was able to import cv2 just fine and run some basic image I/O commands. This issue started occurring when I tried to use VideoCapture. But now I can't import opencv at all.

I have tried closing and reopening the terminal emulator and that did not work.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: The python_scripts directory listing is:

```
cameo.py      filters.py   managers.pyc     rects.pyc        utils.py
cameo.py.org  filters.pyc  MyOutputVid.avi  stream_video.py  utils.pyc
cascades      io.py        MyPic.png        tags             video_stream.py
depth.py      io.pyc       notes.txt        trackers.py
depth.pyc     managers.py  rects.py         trackers.pyc
```

cascades is a directory with .xml files:

```
haarcascade_eye.xml              haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml
haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml  haarcascade_mcs_nose.xml
```

Comment: What exactly does this scripts directory contain aside from .py files? Can you post the directory listing?

Comment: Check that you don't have any files named *cv2.py* and/or *scipy.py* in your directory.

Comment: Okay, I added the directory listing. I don't have cv2.py or scipy.py files.

Comment: Try to rename `io.py` to something else *and* remove `io.pyc`. Python already has an I/O module, which might be overriden by this one. However the error doesn't seem to be related...

Comment: Removing io.py fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Sterling Please post the fix as an answer (and accept it) so that others can find the solution quickly.

Answer (score 4):

As Bakuriu stated, the problem was occurring because python already has an I/O module and my directory contained a io.py file. The issue was fixed by renaming the io.py and io.pyc files.